# HTML/CSS/JS Elements positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

have a problem. At first look at this HTML

```
<div id="map" style="background-image: url(map.png); width: 700; height: 600;">
  <div id="dot1" onMouseOver=expand(this) onMouseOut=shrink(this)></div>
  <div id="dot2" onMouseOver=expand(this) onMouseOut=shrink(this)></div>
</div>
```

and I have next JS code

```
function expand(element) {
  element.style.height = '100px';
}
function shrink(element) {
  element.style.height = '20px';
}
```

IDEA is: imagine map and multiple "red dots" on it on mouse over it's expanding to 100x100, getting white background and text inside about this spot. Only one problem is - how to make other dots stick to the map while one of them is expanded?

For example user is looking on "top" spot, and every else under current one is moving down for ~100px (exactly amount of expanding 1st one)

It looks fine at  **position : relative** but only while you're not looking inside.
Absolute/fixed? - Bad option. I have to calculate user screen size / client size and place every "dot"
OR calculate MAP's left/top offset and make every dot map_offset_Left+myLeft

Maybe there is a way to set them dependent from MAP div and be independent from each other?

Ty

Comment: `width: 700; height: 600;`? Units are *required*

Comment: I have no clue what you want. But if the `#map` has `position:relative` then all the divs inside of it can be `position:absolute`

Comment: what if you create a container with relative position, and dots with absolute position inside that container !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the map to `position: relative`, its absolutely positioned descendants will then be positioned with respect to *the map* and not the window.